# Index duplicates from the list using Linq

Tags: linq

Suppose I have a list of strings

```
var data = new List<string>{"fname", "phone",  "lname", "home", "home", "company", "phone", "phone"};
```

I would like to list all values and add index to duplicates like this

```
fname,
phone,
lname,
home,
home[1],
company,
phone[1],
phone[2]
```

or like this

```
fname,
phone[0],
lname,
home[0],
home[1],
company,
phone[1],
phone[2]
```

The both solutions would work for me.

Is that possible with Linq?

Comment: in current list you want to add index?

Comment: Does the order of the result matter?

Answer (score 1):

You can use LINQ `GroupBy` to gather the matches, and then the counting version of `Select` to append the indexes.

```
var ans = data.GroupBy(d => d).SelectMany(dg => dg.Select((d, n) => n == 0 ? d : $"{d}[{n}]"));
```